# rails selection quantity javascript get class not working index

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What want to do:
I creating ec site by ROR. What I want to do is can select the quantity each items in checkout page(Specifically, make plus and minus button then select the quantity).

The variable are @items and @user_items_quantity and Im adding index number on it.

Then what I mean, getting the (div class) in Javascript which is had index number and I want to edit quantity and show it.

But impossible to get (div class with index) in js each items. I was thinking to roop "for" in js but I can't.

Can you tell me how I work out please?

```
_user_basket_items.html.erb

<% @items.zip(@user_items_quantity).each.with_index(1) do | (item, uiq), index | %>
　<div class="entry value-minus quantity-minus[#{index}]" id="value-minus">&nbsp;</div>

　<div class="entry value score-value quantity-score[#{index}]" id="score-value"><%= uiq %></div>

　<div class="entry value-plus active quantity-plus[#{index}]" id="value-plus">&nbsp;</div>
<% end %>
```

///

```
item_quantity.js

var add = document.getElementsByClassName( "quantity-plus" )["#{index}".to_i];
var remove = document.getElementsByClassName( "quantity-minus" )["#{index}".to_i];
var scoreValue = document.getElementsByClassName( "quantity-score" )["#{index}".to_i];
var int = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    int = parseInt(scoreValue.innerHTML, 10)+1;
    scoreValue.innerHTML = int;
  });

remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
    int = parseInt(scoreValue.innerHTML, 10)-1;
    scoreValue.innerHTML = int;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

the css classes that you are generating looks like this:

```html
<div class="entry value-minus quantity-minus[1]"
```

or

```html
<div class="entry value-minus quantity-minus[2]"
```

but your javascript is looking for `document.getElementsByClassName( "quantity-minus" )` with a mix of ruby syntax (`["#{index}".to_i]`) and js. Is your js template parsing ruby? You don't provide how `index` is initialized.

if it is, I would change the javascript as follows:

```js
var add = document.getElementsByClassName( "quantity-minus[#{index.to_i}]" );
```

If your template isn't parsing ruby, you have to find another way.

As a side note, in your partial you are iterating over a list and giving static ids to the elements (`id="value-minus"`) you should try avoid doing that